# Is there any way with which I can stop http processing unknown methods?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

We are using Spring MVC framework, and have a button on our storefront on clicking on the button, we rarely receive the following error on console.

```
INFO | jvm 1 | main | 2017/06/28 13:08:03.644 | Jun 28, 2017 1:08:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
INFO | jvm 1 | main | 2017/06/28 13:08:03.644 | SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [DispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Error while processing internal filterchain. Exception occurred at chain position: 8 of 11. Current filter: 'FilterChainProxy[Filter Chains: [[ Ant [pattern='/_ui/**'], []], [ Ant [pattern='/steeldeals/**'], []], [ Ant [pattern='/checkout/**'], [org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter@6ccd9b91, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@2ea08465, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@2c541acd, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@45ab9f77, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@672615d, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@3f5623f9, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@3053d0eb, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4eb90d16, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@570a47ba, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@63eb30fa, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@65dca055]], [ com.amc.storefront.security.ExcludeUrlRequestMatcher@27f047cf, [org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter@ffa7b85, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@5c360f5, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@5e1277c7, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@e75da11, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@5b3f9981, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@2c7712f4, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@3d7d67fa, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter@74356d9f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@5fb01d53, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@23556539, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@3b68934e, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@4e9f045a]]]]'!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.springframework.http.HttpMethod.PROPFIND] with root cause
INFO | jvm 1 | main | 2017/06/28 13:08:03.644 | java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.springframework.http.HttpMethod.PROPFIND
INFO | jvm 1 | main | 2017/06/28 13:08:03.644 | at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:236)
INFO | jvm 1 | main | 2017/06/28 13:08:03.644 | at org.springframework.http.HttpMethod.valueOf(HttpMethod.java:27)
INFO | jvm 1 | main | 2017/06/28 13:08:03.644 | at org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:125)
INFO | jvm 1 | main | 2017/06/28 13:08:03.644 | at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.getAttributes(DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.java:86)
INFO | jvm 1 | main | 2017/06/28 13:08:03.644 | at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:130)
INFO | jvm 1 | main | 2017/06/28 13:08:03.644 | at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
INFO | jvm 1 | main | 2017/06/28 13:08:03.644 | at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
INFO | jvm 1 | main | 2017/06/28 13:08:03.644 | at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
INFO | jvm 1 | main | 2017/06/28 13:08:03.644 | at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
```

We are using the following code snippet in spring-security-config.xml

```
<security:http pattern="/_ui/**" security="none"/>
<security:http pattern="/SteelDeals/**" security="none"/>

<!-- Security config for checkout - it has its own login page -->
<security:http disable-url-rewriting="true" pattern="/checkout/**" use-expressions="true">
  <security:anonymous username="anonymous" granted-authority="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
    <security:session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="fixation" />

    <!--<security:session-management session-fixation-protection="none" />-->

    <!-- SSL / AUTHENTICATED pages -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/checkout/j_spring_security_check" requires-channel="https"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/checkout*"  requires-channel="https"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/checkout/**"  requires-channel="https"/>
```

Comment: code and configuration

Comment: Unclear what you want. The server is already not processing the `PROPFIND` method, because if fails with an "unknown method" error. What else should it do for an unknown method?

Comment: Add it to the question in order to format it

Comment: I have added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the dispatcherServlet to dispatch only the methods you want to process. However, you wn't be able to process non existent HTTP methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already rejecting the wrong methods, You are getting this error it means there is some problem in your client code (code which is accessing your controller e.g. ui code).

However, if you want to define a specific method for your controller url you can do by using `method` property of `@RequestMapping` annotation

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bucket", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
public Collection<BucketResponse> getBucket() {
    return service.getBucket();
}
```